# How can I combine multiple lines of text into one line in Python with a delimiter to separate them with big files (4gb+)

Tags: python-3.x, concatenation

I´m using this code to concatenate lines, but it doesn´t work with big files. What is the solution to concatenate without dump a big file all in the memory? I need to add a Delimiter "|", this one between the lines. This code works fine, but doesn´t work fine with a big size file.

```
current = None 
parts = [] 
with open('DEFIS.TXT', 'r', encoding="utf-8", errors="ignore") as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('D1000'):
            current = [line.strip()]
            parts.append(current)
        elif current is not None:
            current.append(line.strip())

with open('DEFIS-OUT.TXT', 'w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(('|'.join(part) for part in parts)))
```

Comment: Keyword: "streaming" (eg. read one line, write one line. repeat.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read from input file and write to output file at same time, for example:

```
current = []

with open('DEFIS.TXT', 'r') as f_in, open('DEFIS-OUT.TXT', 'w') as f_out:
    for line in map(str.strip, f_in):
        if line.startswith('D1000'):
            if current:
                print('|'.join(current), file=f_out)
            current = []
        current.append(line)
    #save last chunk (if any):
    if current:
        print('|'.join(current), file=f_out)
```

---

If `DEFIS.TXT` contains:

```
D1000
1
2
3
D1000
4
5
6
D1000
7
8
9
```

Then `DEFIS-OUT.TXT` after running the script will contain:

```
D1000|1|2|3
D1000|4|5|6
D1000|7|8|9
```